# Mongoose not returning a query resulting in documents >80,000

Tags: mongoose

I am using Nodejs express app.
Mongoose is not returning a query resulting in documents >80,000 .
It is not returning any error also, it just hangs

Answer (score 0):

You should limit the query size to manageable chunk. It is meaningless to fetch so many records from database at one time.